# How to update field in firebase document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I want to update a field in a firebase document.

Right now , I am accessing the document collection like this
However I am having trouble setting teh shares field of the doc to shares+=1 ?
What am i doing wrong here in the set method?

```
const buyStock = async () => {
const q = await query(
  collection(db, 'myStocks'),
  where('ticker', '==', props.name)
);
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
  // simply update the record

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.id.set({
      shares: doc.id.data().shares+=1
    })
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc, doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. To update a document, you need a reference to that document. You can get this with:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  doc.ref.update({
    shares: doc.data().shares+=1
  })
});
```

You can also use the built-in [atomic increment operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value):

```
doc.ref.update({
  shares: increment(1)
})
```

Comment: i'm getting an error doc.ref.update() is not a function?

Comment: Ah yeah, that might be `updateDoc(doc.ref, ...)`. But you should've gotten a similar error for your ` doc.id.set()` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the set method on the 'id' field. Try to remove that. So just do

```
doc.set({
  shares: doc.data().shares+=1
})
```

give that a shot.  If that doesn't work, i'd try updating a document that is not part of a query snapshot.

Comment: i get an error doc.set is not a function?